# How to ignore config file until database is created

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button that when pressed will make a database so it can run on different localhosts but the page isn't loading right when I added an isset['register']

It displays errors in the text box

[code here](https://pastebin.com/jw0XpUzV)

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
code
}
```

added that line thinking it would ignore the 'require_once config.php'

Have the same error on my login page.

Worked perfect until I added a button to create the database

Comment: Please add your relevant code here and do not past everything to pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `error_reporting(0);` at 2nd line

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);

 // Include config file
if(isset($_POST['register'])){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if a database exists is:

```
SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'dbname';
```

If database with the name 'dbname' doesn't exist, you get an empty set. If it does exist, you get one row.

Comment: Where will I add/replace that?